Filter processing - frequency to time, truncate taps, and back to frequency domain (using Python)
I read a paper about adaptive filtering specifying the following procedure:
$$ q_{FIR}(k) \overset{\textrm{FIR}}{\longleftarrow} q(k)$$
The framework processes the input signal (sampled in $f_s$ sampling rate) using STFT and works batch by batch.
Suppose I have a filter in the frequency domain $q(k)$ (obtained in an adaptive manner, not from a predesigned function like Butterworth or SciPy design-FIR).

Take the adaptive filter $q(k)$.
Transform the filter to the time domain, i.e. of the general FIR type $y[n] = \sum_{i=0}^{N_{org}} b_i x[n-i]$ (how $N_{org}$ is determined?).
Truncate the filter, to a given number of taps $N_{trunc}$. Then have $y[n] = \sum_{i=0}^{N_{trunc}} b_i x[n-i]$.
Reconvert the truncated filter ($b_0, b_1, ... , b_{N_{trunc}}$) to the frequency domain $q_{FIR}(k)$.
Perform the filtering in the frequency domain: $y_{filt}(k) = q_{FIR}(k)^* u(k)$.

I have two questions about it:

What is it good for?
How do I implement it in Python (using NumPy and SciPy)?

The naive way to do it is just to use np.fft.irfft to go from freq to time, then zero all the values after $N_{trunc}$ (e.g. q_time[N_trunc:]=0) and then go back with np.fft.rfft.

Your method as described will have serious issues with time domain aliasing, so it won't work in most cases. This being said, time variant domain frequency domain processing is quite common (echo cancellation, surround decoders, sub-band processing etc). However it's mathematically complicated and typically doesn't involve the extra IFFT/turncate/FFT steps.
